# xcode 8 beta - Error compiling to the real iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I couldn't find any related topic so I am starting the new one.
I have `macOS Sierra` and latest `xcode 8`.

When I attach my `iPhone` to macbook and try to build even clean project in `xcode` I get following swift compiler errors:

Attempting to use the forward class '`UIViewController`' as superclass of '`UIActivityViewController`'

Attempting to use the forward class '`UIViewController`' as superclass of '`UIAlertController`'

And so on. Error count is 21 and is always same no matter what project I choose.

Someone have same problem? Any solution?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: So I have installed xcode directly from App store rather than download from dev apple page and it works now. I assume its bug. So its resolved now.

Comment: Add this comment as a proper answer and I upvote. Xcode 8.1 beta fixes the issue as well.